# C# converting matrix to String is slow for large matrices

Tags: c#, serialization, tostring

I have a Matrix class that provides a method `ToString()` which is used in serialization code.

```
public override string ToString()                           
// Function returns matrix as a string
// e.g. "Rows=3,Columns=3,Data= 1.00 0.50 0.75 | 0.50 1.00 0.25 | 0.75 0.25 1.00 |"
{
    string s = "Rows=" + rows.ToString() + ",Columns=" + cols.ToString() + ",Data= ";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) s += String.Format("{0:G17}", mat[i, j]) + " ";
        s += "| ";
    }
    return s;
}
```

My use case is a matrix with 10,000+ rows and 2 columns.  It takes around 10 seconds to execute which is too slow.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  Note I need full double precision serialized.

It feels like the code is inefficient since the reverse operation when I deserialize takes under a second (this uses `Convert.ToDouble(string)` in a loop).

Any ideas why this is inefficient?

Comment: You could use [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you add to a string it has to create a new one and destroy the old one which is slow.  Use a `StringBuilder` instead it will just add to the string builder instead of create a new one.

```
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("Rows=" + rows.ToString() + ",Columns=" + cols.ToString() + ",Data= ");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) s.AppendFormat("{0:G17}", mat[i, j]) + " ");
        s.Append( "| ");
   }
    return s.ToString();
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder

Comment: `s.AppendFormat("{0:G17}", mat[i, j]) + " ");` looks strange and won't even compile. Probably better will be `s.AppendFormat("{0:G17} ", mat[i, j]);`

Comment: Thank you Ken, this solved the speed issue perfectly. I was not aware of the StringBuilder object.